# Slow app with LocalStorage and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, pouchdb

I created an app that stores, compares, filters and takes statistics out of a collection of records. I've done it so it works offline, as in some user cases the user might not have constant (or at all) access to internet.

My problem is that after I've included ~60 records, the app starts to behave **really** slow. For instance, I list a collection of simple objects from LocalStorage into a ng-model (Select list), and after those ~60 records are in, to open the Select box will be seriously slowed down.

What could the problem be? I'm thinking, either some function is sucking more resources than necessary, or LocalStorage is not intended for such uses?

I'm starting to get into PouchDB, would you say that migrating all to Pouch instead of LocalStorage would be a good move?

I can't paste the whole controller here as it's huge, but I've put an online version for testing. You can see it [here](http://cccctanger.com/fleet/).

For you not to have to create 60 records just to see the effect, you can [download this CSV](http://cccctanger.com/fleet/60records.csv) and import it in the app.

In order to import, the pass for Edit Mode is: **admin**

Let's see if someone has a tip for this one!

Comment: I've run into some performance issues using `ng-click` on a large record set. I wouldn't say 60 is a ton, but it does seem to break down around that number.

Comment: Well, something tells me that Angular should be able to handle more than that. Can't it be something else than ng-click? Maybe some watch function overdoing it?

Comment: 60 records is tiny ... something wrong in your app code. Also something wrong when `controller is huge`. Controller's should be very lean

Comment: I learned Angular doing this app. I don't have a programmers background, faced trouble when trying to split the js code (for instance to put directives somewhere else...)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are storing all your records inside a single LocalStorage value (with the key being `recordspax`). So yeah, that will get quite slow, because your app has to 1) JSON parse/stringify and 2) store/retrieve *the entire list* every time you read/write data to the database.

Basically you are reading your entire database in and out of disk for every operation. Since both LocalStorage and JSON stringify/parse happen synchronously on the main thread, it can block DOM rendering and will thus slow down your app.

PouchDB could be a help here, but you could also benefit from something simpler like [LocalForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage), or simply changing your DB design so that every record has its own key/value rather than storing everything into a single key with a single value.

(Both LocalForage and PouchDB use IndexedDB/WebSQL rather than LocalStorage, meaning that database operations are not synchronous and do not block the DOM. However, you still don't want to stuff everything into a single document and therefore read the entire DB in and out of disk. :))

Comment: I think I grasp what you mean. But then, if I don't read the entire document, how can I, for instance, filter results with AngularJS? Right now I have the ability to show, for instance, only records from last week. In order to do this Angular needs to iterate through the whole list of records... I think I'm missing one or two important concepts here : )

Comment: I just realized you are _that_ Nolan Lawson! I saw your PouchDB vidcast 2 days ago, and it kinda triggered the question. How would you organize this kind of data then? I'm new in this DB thingy, my brains don't really know how to wrap around these complex structure concepts...

Comment: Heh, glad you like the video! :) Yeah, it's actually pretty easy to loop through LocalStorage; it's just: `for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) { console.log(localStorage.key(i)); }`. So you can use any unique identifier as the key, and then the document as your value, then loop through `localStorage` when you need to show all documents. E.g. `localStorage[mydoc.id] = JSON.stringify(mydoc)`.