# Rethinking data structure using LocalStorage and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, local-storage

I built an app using LocalStorage.

It stores a significant amount of objects under a single key, which I recently discovered that is reason for the DOM to be blocked, as the app has to JSON parse/stringify and store/retrieve the entire list every time I read or write to the "database".

Quoting an [answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635398/2459543):

> Since both LocalStorage and JSON stringify/parse happen synchronously on the main thread, it can block DOM rendering and will thus slow down your app.

The data insertion looks like this:

```
$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();
$scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList,
                comments: [],
                arrival: '',
                inserted: '',
                cancelled:'',
                duration:''
            }
        );
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

Being so, I need to re-think the whole way I store and read that.

This way of doing it for me it made sense, as I was using AngularJS to read, filter and compare the objects stored in this one single key.

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter:dateFilter | filter: search )" 
     ng-hide="is.cancelled && (!record.cancelled || record.cancelled === '') || has.comment && (!record.comment || record.comment === '')" 
     ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'msf-commented' : record.comment}" 
     ng-hide="!record.arrival && !record.cancelled" 
     ng-show="record.cancelled">
```

Any tips on how to migrate this, to which system and why?

I'd like to keep the AngularJS functionality. So if I don't read the whole file every time, how can I filter records?

You can see an [working example of the app here](http://cccctanger.com/fleet/).

I realize **I'm missing key concepts** on the way data should be stored and read. Any tip pointing to documentation/theory on that matter aside from direct answers, would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: I saw your app. And I see that you are saving every car moment in the localstorage. Since yours is a single page app, why dont you simply ajax post the data and save the record at server end ?

Comment: 2 ng-hide and an ng-show on your repeater doesn't make sense and is creating way too many watches

Comment: @brute_force its supposed to be an offline app! Can I do that using LS as "server end"?

Answer (score 1):

one improvement might be to replace the ng-show and ng-hide directives with a custom filter for displaying the data.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('showhide', function() {

    return function(record, isCancelled) {

        var hide1 = isCancelled && (!record.cancelled || record.cancelled === '') || has.comment && (!record.comment || record.comment === '');

        var hide2 = !record.arrival && !record.cancelled;

        return !hide1 && !hide2;
    };
});
```

and call it like

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter:dateFilter | filter: search | showhide:is.cancelled )" 
     ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'msf-commented' : record.comment}">
```

this depends on all the data to be loaded into a javascript variable and filtered by your script. i assume that you data is not so big as this leads to a problem, e.g. not more than 10000 objects in the list. DOM performance is more about how many items really get rendered. every ng-hide element actually gets rendered and then it will be removed from the list again.

you then have to store this list somewhere in a variable that gets only read once and only write updates to the localstorage object. you do this by using a service that holds your data.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).service('dataService', function() {

    var data = ... // get from localStorage
    return {
        get: data,
        save: function(){
            // put the variable 'data' to localStorage
        }
    }
}
```

then in your controller you do

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataService){
    $scope.recordList = dataService.get();
});
```

from there on you can modify the array without reading it again and if you did any updates to the array you can call save() on the dataService object.

The other option would be to use something like pouchdb or dexie.js and make a service that gets all the filters set and queries the database directly. pouchdb is good if you want to sync the data to a couchdb instance. dexie.js might be easier if you only want to store the data in the client.

but i don't think that you outgrow the localStorage solution so fast.